# How to compute the number of unique values with a for-loop in base R?

Tags: r, loops, unique, multiple-columns, names

I have a big `data frame` and would like to count the number of `unique` values per column using a `for-loop` and base R - so no `n_distinct` or `apply` family functions.
It has columns that aren't `numerical` or `integer`

Answer (score 2):

If we need a `for` loop - initialize a `list` to store the output, then loop over the sequence of columns, extract the column (`df1[[i]]`), get the `unique` values, find the `length` and store that in the corresponding list element.  Note that `list` is just one way to store the object in case if the object is complex.  Otherwise, we can also do `out <- integer(ncol(df))` as initialization which returns a integer vector

```
out <- vector('list', ncol(df1))
for(i in seq_along(df1))
  out[[i]] <- length(unique(df1[[i]]))
```